# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set' along with with clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure logic as below. I get

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.

as error, please suggest me the solution.

```
Declare @VAL int
Declare @Region bigint

drop table Tempqq

Select * Into Tempqq From dbo.split(@SpokeFolderList, ',')

while (Select Count(*) From Tempqq) > 0
begin
       Select Top 1 @VAL = Tempqq.val From Tempqq

        ;With MyCount AS
        ( 
            Select DispatchToRegionId ,FolderNo, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY FolderNo DESC) as Row 
            from tblTransite where FolderNo = @VAL  group by DispatchToRegionId,FolderNo
        )
        set @Region =( Select  top 1 DispatchToRegionId  from MyCount
                        order by Row desc  )

         print @VAL
         Delete Tempqq Where Tempqq.val = @VAL
 end
```

Comment: Use Select instead of Set.

Comment: That delete should have a `from` i.e. `delete from tempqq`

Comment: Unrelated but: don't prefix `with` with a `;`. The semicolon `;` is used to *terminate* a statement. https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
if i remove that ; I get error 
Incorrect syntax near 'MyCount'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.

Comment: That's what I said: you should terminate *each* statement (and what is the recommendation in my link). Not only start CTEs with the statement termination character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
Declare @VAL int
Declare @Region bigint

drop table Tempqq

Select * Into Tempqq From dbo.split(@SpokeFolderList, ',')

while (Select Count(*) From Tempqq) > 0
begin
       Select Top 1 @VAL = Tempqq.val From Tempqq

        ;With MyCount AS
        ( 
            Select DispatchToRegionId ,FolderNo, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY FolderNo DESC) as Row 
            from tblTransite where FolderNo = @VAL  group by DispatchToRegionId,FolderNo
        )
         Select  top 1 DispatchToRegionId into @Region  from MyCount
                        order by Row desc

         print @VAL
         Delete Tempqq Where Tempqq.val = @VAL
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

> CTE is more like a VIEW rather than a stored procedure. It doesn't
>   seem to be correct syntax.

And `Delete` should have a `From` keyword

Try this

```
Declare @VAL int
Declare @Region bigint

Drop table Tempqq
Select * Into Tempqq From dbo.split(@SpokeFolderList, ',')

While (Select Count(*) From Tempqq) > 0
Begin
       Select Top 1 @VAL = Tempqq.val From Tempqq   
       ;With MyCount AS
       ( 
        Select DispatchToRegionId ,FolderNo, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY FolderNo DESC) as Row 
        From tblTransite where FolderNo = @VAL  group by DispatchToRegionId,FolderNo
       )
       Select @Region =(Select  top 1 DispatchToRegionId  from MyCount order by Row desc)    
       Print @VAL
       Delete From Tempqq Where Tempqq.val = @VAL
 End
```